# Fill area with geom_area under negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

It seems like I have a very simple problem:

I created a plot like this with ggplot2:

[Negative Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN4tk.png)

Using this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- read.table(header=T, text='  x y
              1   -1
              2   -1.5
              3  -1.6
              4  -1.7
              5  -1')

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
geom_area(size=1,colour="red")
```

As you can see, the graph values are negative.

I want to fill the area under the graph line.

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVur8.png)

The duplicate path doesn't help me with that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data.

Comment: Also,  please add the code you used to produce the plot.

Comment: I have to agree that the duplicate doesn't answer the question. And the duplicate is actually much more contrived than this simple question. So please vote to reopen.

Comment: Here is an answer in a gist: https://gist.github.com/ziggystar/4e8648e8f668050bee57027af6093185 . It applies a shifting transform to the y-axis. You have to figure out the correct shift value yourself, though. I'll turn this into an answer once the question is reopened.