# Invert colored area geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am sure it is easy to solve this question.

I am trying to fill the area below the line I plot from "mydata" using `ggplot2`.

here the example:

```
a = seq(10, 100, 5)
b = -(runif(19, 0, 50))
mydata <- data.frame(a, b)

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_area()
```

`geom_bar` fills above the line, considering the area the one from 0 and the values (negative). I want to fill the other area and I think I should delimit the area I want to colour, but I do not know how.

The script above is just an easy example. 
My real script is

```
ggplot(data = ctd, aes(x = Longitude, y = Depth)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = NO3_uM)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(my_colours)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = NO3_uM), binwidth = 2, colour = "black", alpha = 0.2) +
  #geom_contour(aes(z = NO3_uM), breaks = 20, colour = "black") +

  geom_point(data = ctd, aes(x = Longitude, y = Depth),
             colour = 'black', size = 3, alpha = 1, shape = 15) +
  geom_area(data = trsect, aes(x = Longitude, y = Depth), fill = "black")+
  ylim(-320,0)
```

my result is:

[image]
[image]

I want to colour the other area of the "mountain"

Comment: You want to fill both above and below the line, or you want to just fill below the line?

Comment: @camille, I would like to fill only below the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_ribbon` for this. `geom_area` is a special case of `geom_ribbon` where `ymin` is set to 0. Instead, set `ymin` to the minimum of your y-values, i.e. `ymin = min(b)`. Or if you wanted some extra space, you could do `ymin = min(b) - 2` or something like that.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a = seq(10, 100, 5)
b = -(runif(19, 0, 50))
mydata <- data.frame(a, b)

ggplot(mydata) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = a, ymin = min(b), ymax = b))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make a vector to define a new area.

```
qq = rep(-60, length(b))
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x = a, y = b))+
 geom_area(data=data.frame(qq), aes(y=qq), fill='red', alpha=0.5) +
 geom_area(aes(y=b), col='black')
```

Which produces

[image]

You can play with `fill` and the `theme` to have a different set of options (It is not quite clear what's your desired output).

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x = a, y = b))+
   geom_area(data=data.frame(qq), aes(y=qq),fill='red', alpha=0.5) +
   geom_area(aes(y=b), fill='white') + theme_void()
```

Which produces

[image]

Comment: This is a nice option, but unfortunately, it is not convenient in my case, because this area is not the only data I have to plot, and this way will cover everything.

Comment: My question is similar to this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656444/fill-area-with-geom-area-under-negative-values?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @LucaStirnimann We can definitely work it out but if `this area is not the only data I have to plot`, it would be really really nice to have a more defined idea of what is the expected output. The link shows a graph that almost the answer posted here (you would only need to add the axis and tweak a few things). Please provide at least a drawing of the expected plot